# scores returned by the alpha function in psych pkg are incorrect

Tags: r, psych

Please consider the following code to obtain scores from the `alpha` function

```r
library(psych)

vars <- c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp', 'hp')
df <- mtcars[0:10, vars]

alpha_results <- alpha(df, check.keys=TRUE)
df$scores <- alpha_results$scores

print(head(df))
```

```
 mpg cyl disp  hp  scores
21.0   6  160 110 154.750
21.0   6  160 110 154.750
22.8   4  108  93 136.550
21.4   6  258 110 179.150
18.7   8  360 175 222.075
18.1   6  225 105 170.475
```

```
 Item statistics 
      n raw.r std.r r.cor r.drop  mean   sd
mpg- 10  0.86  0.94  0.91   0.85 343.6  2.9
cyl  10  0.91  0.96  0.94   0.91   5.8  1.5
disp 10  0.98  0.93  0.90   0.85 208.6 90.4
hp   10  0.94  0.95  0.94   0.85 122.8 51.4
```

Based on the [doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.9.12/topics/alpha) of the function:

> Scores are by default simply the average response for all items that a participant took. If cumulative=TRUE, then these are sum scores. Note, this is dangerous if there are lots of missing values

However, for example, the score for the first obs should be

```
(-21.0 + 6 + 160 + 110)/4 = 63.75
```

But the result was 154.750 instead.

Comment: By setting check.keys = TRUE, you have asked for negatively correlated items to be reverse scored.  The process of negatively keying is just multiplying by -1.  Then the items are just added up (to get the scores).    You don't actually say what the stata result was.  It would help if you could report that.

Comment: Hi, @WilliamRevelle, I didn't realize you are the dev. I just check the source code but didn't find how the scores are calculated. Please see my updated post. Btw, is this psych pkg on GitHub for issue tracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alpha` function is not really meant for finding scores of data with drastically different ranges.  Based upon the normal use case of items with equal ranges, it adjusts reversed scored items by subtracting those items from the maximum value +  minimum value.   In the case of the cars example, that is 360 + 4 or 364.  Thus, the first value is (364 - 21 + 6 + 160 + 110)/4 = 154.75 as reported.

The `scoreItems` function will find the local min and max (as does `alpha`); or you can specify them.

To get what you want, you should use the `scoreItems` function and specify the keys as well as `min=0` and `max=0`.

Note that I use the `cs` function (from `psychTools`, adapted from `Hmisc`) to add `""` in the  `keys <- list` command

```
keys <- list(cars=cs(-mpg, cyl,disp,hp))
test1 <-scoreItems(keys,df,min=0,max=0)
test1$scores
                     cars
Mazda RX4          63.750
Mazda RX4 Wag      63.750
Datsun 710         45.550
Hornet 4 Drive     88.150
Hornet Sportabout 131.075
```